# KVM switch for Cinema 4k?

Tags: monitors, kvm, display-port

I just got a new LG 31MU97-B that I'd like to hook up to my PC and Mac, but I can't find a [mini-/]displayport KVM switch that supports full Cinema 4k (4096x2160) at 60Hz, only UHD (3840x2160).

I'm hoping there's something that my Google searches have missed, or someone else has had luck with a UHD-spec'd KVM still outputting Cinema 4k by sheer luck.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found something! After looking for a few months, I came across [this press release](http://www.aten.com/us/en/products/kvm/desktop-kvm-switches/cs782dp/#.WBOTiOErJE4) for the Aten 2-Port USB DisplayPort KVM Switch that specifically mentions support for displayport resolutions up to 4096x2160 @60Hz.

I found it for sale on newegg and Amazon, and it looks like it's been out for while, but both sites only listed support for UHD resolution (3840x2160). I got it, plugged it in, and it worked great! Full resolution and refresh rate on both my computers.

Comment: Could you have a look at the [similar question I just posted](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/9050/7888)?  I don't *think* the CS782DP you purchased fits all my requirements ([one Amazon review](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R3V2I63J6UPCGS/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B01AH0BMPO) mentions window resizing issues), but I'd like your take.